# Couchbase on Openshift

Tags: openshift, couchbase

Has anyone tried to create couchbase cluster on openshift ? We are not able to create routes on the 8091 port and expose the webconsole outside. The service is created with the app. 
The route resolves to 503 Service Unavailable.

Comment: Is this on OpenShift Online or OpenShift 3? Instructions for Couchbase on OpenShift 3 are available at: http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/december/couchbase-on-openshift-3

Comment: Hey Arun, Thanks for your comment! I did look at your post earlier. The issue is I am just not able to expose the 8091 port via route. We are testing on openshift Origin (v1.1.1.1 )

Comment: Can you give us some more information. For example - what is the service descriptor look like? Can you paste in the commands you are trying to use. Can you also let us know where you are deploying it (the all in one, custom setup, Openshift Enterprise Ansible...)

Comment: What does the output of "oc get routes" show?  do you get an error message?

Comment: This is on openshift origin v1.1.1.1. I deployed another app and was able to create a route to it.

Comment: Hi @ArunGupta I am also trying to deploy an app which uses couchbase, followed your blog "http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/december/couchbase-on-openshift-3". How to expose svc on particular port such as 8091 here? Also could you please let me know the link for blog which has details on "How to deploy an application to OpenShift and use this Couchbase" as I dont want to hardcode couchbase IP in my app, would like to do using Environment variables. Thanks much for the help

Comment: I've not tried that part yet, @TheSteve0 might be able to help you with that.

Comment: @ArunGupta thanks a lot for response, so my other question was is it possible to expose service on particular port? Because I see couchbase uses these ports        8091/TCP,8092/TCP,8093/TCP,11207/TCP,11210/TCP,11211/TCP,18091/TCP,18092/TCP. Where console is running on 8091, can we expose svc on this port only, so that I can access console externally ? Thanks again for help!

Comment: I blogged about how to expose an external LoadBalancer for Kubernetes on Amazon: http://blog.couchbase.com/2016/march/kubernetes-cluster-google-cloud-expose-service and Google Cloud: http://blog.couchbase.com/2016/march/kubernetes-cluster-google-cloud-expose-service. I'd presume there is a similar mechanism for OpenShift as well.

Comment: @priyank you will have to setup router with your openshift origin. once you have it, you can expose any service in openshift to external network using "oc expose svc " or manually setting specific routes on particular ports.

Comment: @cloudnoob hey thanks, I have setup router , but main concern is that is there a way to expose service on particular port? My service exposes these ports "8091/TCP,8092/TCP,8093/TCP". I use command :
"oc expose svc testapp --hostname=<public_host>"  how it knows which port to use??

Comment: @priyank yes, the way I have done is, manually setup routes on particular ports , you can log in through the openshift console UI Browse > routes and setup the correct hostname for each port. ( and also define if it is https )

Comment: @cloudnoob : thanks :) I have been doing this always through CLI, didn't know webconsole also has this feature. thanks again